# Problems installing libpq-devel in Fedora 39

Tags: linux, postgresql, fedora

When I try to install libpq-devel i get this error:

```
sudo dnf install libpq-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 2:22:39 ago on Tue 05 Dec 2023 12:40:17 PM EET.
Error: 
 Problem: package libpq-devel-15.3-1.fc39.i686 from fedora requires libpq(x86-32) = 15.3-1.fc39, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - libpq-15.3-1.fc39.i686 from fedora  does not belong to a distupgrade repository
  - package libpq-devel-15.3-1.fc39.x86_64 from fedora requires libpq(x86-64) = 15.3-1.fc39, but none of the providers can be installed
  - problem with installed package libpq5-16.0-42PGDG.f39.x86_64
  - installed package libpq5-16.0-42PGDG.f39.x86_64 obsoletes libpq provided by libpq-15.3-1.fc39.x86_64 from fedora
  - package libpq5-16.0-42PGDG.f39.x86_64 from pgAdmin4 obsoletes libpq provided by libpq-15.3-1.fc39.x86_64 from fedora
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

How can I solve this problem ? I need to install this package to be able to run postgresql server.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install a package from the Fedora repository, but that conflicts with the PostgreSQL packages from the PostgreSQL (PGDG) repository that you already have installed.

**Don't do that.** Mixing packages like that will only lead to unpleasant, hard-to-debug problems.

Install the appropriate PGDG package:

```bash
sudo dnf install postgresql16-devel
```

If that gives you trouble, make sure that you have the latest repository package installed:

```bash
sudo dnf install pgdg-fedora-repo
```

If after that update you have a file `/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-fedora-all.repo.rpmnew`, fix your setup like this:

```bash
sudo mv /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-fedora-all.repo.rpmnew /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-fedora-all.repo
```

Comment: `Error: Unable to find a match: postgresql16-devel`.

I tried to install the package because it guided me from psycopg2 package which needs pg_conf file.

Comment: Then you tried to install psycopg2 from the wrong repository.

Comment: I uninstalled `libpq5-16.0-42PGDG.f39.x86_64` and then installed `libpq-15.3-1.fc39.x86_64` (Basically downgraded) packages. Problem solved.